# Filtering data using group by with condition into every group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data in a table like below:

- Table name: `Employee Name`
- Column Name: `Carrier` and `Error`

The contents of the table:

```
**Carrier**  **Error**
  'A'        'Invalid'
  'A'        ''
  'C'        'Invalid'
  'D'         ''
```

I want to get data per group, meaning I have distinct 3 carrier group then I need 3 rows from the table. For example as per above data I need output like below:

```
**Carrier**        **Error**
  'A'               'Invalid'
  'C'               'Invalid'
  'D'                 ''
```

Here carrier 'A' has two rows so I need to display data for 'A' is not nullable first row.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: hi @/gordon , but i have not idea about how to remove null able data form specific group that group has also not null able error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simple grouping like:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Name
    (
      Carrier NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
      Error NVARCHAR(100) NULL
    );


INSERT  INTO Employee_Name
VALUES  ( '''A''', '''Invalid''' ),
        ( '''A''', '''''' ),
        ( '''C''', '''Invalid''' ),
        ( '''D''', '''''' );

--Query
SELECT  Carrier ,
        MAX(Error) Error
FROM    Employee_Name
GROUP BY Carrier;
```

The result will be : [image]